# Get corrupt users with multiple ids values in different column of same table

Tags: mysql

There are around 5 million users in a table having 4 columns, for each value in userid column there needs to be only one sid value in same table. But there are some corrupt records where some userid having multiple sid. How to retrieve these users using mysql query. Please find below the table structure:

**id    userid  sid**

1   12345   a
2   67890   b
3   23456   c
4   45678   d
5   23456   e
6   56789   f
7   78901   g
8   10987   h
9   78901   i
10  45800   j

Here the corrupt records are 23456 and 78901. How to retrieve such user ids in mysql

Comment: get all sid for userids

Comment: `select userid, count(sid) from userstable group by userid having count(sid) > 1`

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to [tag:mysqli] or [tag:mysql-workbench]? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @derpirscher, the query works, but can we also get the relative sid value , all in one query

Comment: You can join the result of this query with the userstable again, to get all respective rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find duplicate entries you can use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```sql
SELECT userid
FROM your_table
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sid) > 1;
```

Comment: `count(distinct sid)` won't return a result if there are two rows with the same userid and same sid. Which seems also like an erroneous situation to me